# Getting Concurrency Issue in Implementation

Tags: service, wso2, abstraction, ballerina

**Package Level**

**PM.bal**

```
public type PM object {

    public isolated function methodA(json config) returns error|http:Response;
    public isolated function methodB(json config) returns error|http:Response;
    public isolated function methodC(json config) returns sql:Client|error;
};
```

**DefaultImplPM.bal**

```
public class DefaultImplPM {
    *PM;
   
    public isolated function methodC(json config) returns sql:Client|error {
        return  new mysql:Client("dbConfig.host", "dbConfig.username", "dbConfig.password", "dbConfig.database");
    }

    public isolated function methodA(json config) returns error|http:Response {
        http:Response response = new;
        response.setJsonPayload("Default methodA is not implemented yet");
        return response;
    }

    public isolated function methodB( json config) returns error|http:Response {
        http:Response response = new;
        response.setJsonPayload("Default methodB is not implemented yet");
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Service level**

**newImpl.bal**

```
import package as pkg;
public class NewImplPM {
    *pkg:PM;
   
    public isolated function methodC(json config) returns sql:Client|error {
        return  new mysql:Client("dbConfig.host", "dbConfig.username", "dbConfig.password", "dbConfig.database");
    }

    public isolated function methodA(json config) returns error|http:Response {
        http:Response response = new;
        response.setJsonPayload("new methodA is not implemented yet");
        return response;
    }

    public isolated function methodB(json config) returns error|http:Response {
        http:Response response = new;
        response.setJsonPayload("new methodB is not implemented yet");
        return response;
    }
}
```

**in service.bal**

```
import package as pkg;

service /fr on new http:Listener(9090) {

    pkg:PM pmVariable;
    public function init() {
        self.pmVariable = new DefaultImplPM();
    }


    resource isolated function post methodD(string c) returns error|http:Response {
        return self.pmVariable.methodA(c);   
    }

    resource isolated function post methodE(string c) returns error|http:Response {
        return self.pmVariable.methodB(c);
    }
}
```

I have some abstract methods for a use case which may have multiple different types of implementation for those methods.   I want to given an basic implementation in a ballerina package level. That will be my default algorithm.  When some one wants to give some additional support with a new algorithm implementation in service level. He/She should be able to do it by including my interface and implement those methods.

With this implementation, I got `concurrent calls will not be made to this method since the service is not an 'isolated' service` warning. How to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the warning, this is because the service object is not `isolated` (nor does it meet the requirements for an `isolated` object to be inferred as one). Concurrent calls will be made to a resource method only if both the object and the method are `isolated`. If the object is not `isolated`, there can still be unsafe access of mutable state.

See [concurrency safety](https://ballerina.io/learn/distinctive-language-features/concurrency/#concurrency-safety), specifically [isolated objects](https://ballerina.io/learn/distinctive-language-features/concurrency/#isolated-objects).

This service is not inferred as `isolated` since it has a non-private mutable field (which is also not accessed within locks, does not meet transfer in/out conditions for an `isolated` object, etc.).

You can explicitly mark the service declaration to identify and fix what's causing it to be non-isolated.

```
isolated service /fr on new http:Listener(9090) {
    ...
}
```

Generally, you would either have to

1. make `PM` an isolated object and `pmVariable` a `final` field or
2. make `pmVariable` a private field and use locks when accessing it and introduce related changes (to ensure that the object is an [isolated root](https://ballerina.io/learn/distinctive-language-features/concurrency/#combine-isolated-function-with-lock))

Comment: I tried your first suggestion `make PM an isolated object and pmVariable a final field`. It is working. Thanks.